# Paypal express is not working for multishipping checkout in magento 1.7.2

Tags: checkout, paypal

I am trying to integrate the paypal express payment method for multishipping checkout and i have already set the variable $canuseformultishiiping="true" but paypal express payment method is not working for multishipping checkout.
Can anyone help me to integrate paypal express for multishipping checkout?
Does paypal express payment method support multishipping checkout in magento? if it does not supported by magento then how can we integrate for multishipping.

Answer (score 3):

As explained [in here also](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/16644/146) Magento's multishipping checkout does not support payment methods that required a redirect to a payment gateway.
The reason for that is beyond my understanding.
And making the multishipping support payment gateways is not an easy task.
If I would want to implement this I would start by looking at how the onepage checkout handles redirects to payment gateways and how it handles the feedback from them.